# How do I pass a list as a list of arguments in racket?

Tags: list, parameters, scheme, racket

I have a statement like this:

```
 ((lambda (a b c) (+ a b c)) 1 2 3) ; Gives 6
```

And I would like to be able to also pass it a list as so:

```
((lambda (a b c) (+ a b c)) (list 1 2 3))
```

...except this doesn't work because the entire list is passed as 'a.' Is there is a way to explode the list into arguments?

What I'm looking for is something similar to the * character in Python. For those of you unfamiliar with the syntax:

```
 def sumthree(a, b, c):
   print a + b + c

 sumthree(1, 2, 3) # Prints 6
 sumthree(*(1, 2, 3)) # Also prints 6
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That operation is called `apply`.

```
(apply + (list 1 2 3))   ; => 6
```

`apply` "expands" the last argument; any previous arguments are passed as is. So these are all the same:

```
(apply + 1 2 3 (list 4 5 6))
(apply + (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))
(+ 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 10):

Pay attention to the following definition

```
(define (a . b) (apply + b))
(a 1)
(a 1 2)
(a 1 2 3)
```

'.' gives you ability to pass any number of arguments to a function. You can still have required arguments

```
(define (f x . xs) (apply x xs)) ;; x is required
(f + 1 2 3) ;; x is +, xs is (1 2 3)
```

Comment: This is actually the original reason I was looking for the apply function. Pretty neat stuff.

Comment: Documentation explaining the use of this syntax: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html